# Cannot set a background colour for a Section element in ie8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

This code works in ie9 but not in ie8.
Although I am using modenizer.js, I am wondering if the problem is that the css is being applied to a section element?

```
function basketBackgroundChange(selectedT) {
    var $sectionGl = $('#Selected').closest("section");
    if (selectedT) {
        $sectionGl.css("background-color", "red;");
    } else {
        $sectionGl.css("background-color", "gray;");
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I guess this won't solve the problem, but you don't need to append a `;` to the value: `"red"` instead of `"red;"`.

Comment: its better to addClass rather than adding css

Comment: Actually that did solve the problem :-). If you are quick and make that the answer before someone else does I will give you a tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to append a `;` when setting a CSS value: use `"red"` instead of `"red;"`.

Comment: As I was thinking to myself "oh no, not another ie8" problem, I didn't see the obvious!